# Which features do html form elements miss

Tags: html, forms, missing-features

I just wondered and wanted to gather together in one place all missing features of our beloved html form elements. 
One example could be missing of horizontal scrollbar in a **listbox**. But I am sure there are a lot of features we would like to see in our form elements by default. 
One missing feature per answer please.
Thank you.

Comment: If you want this to stand a chance of staying open (as there's not one definitive correct answer) you'll have to make it Community Wiki. However, even if you do there's not guarantee that it won't get closed.

Comment: All right, I do agree to make it community wiki.

Comment: But I don't know how to make it Community Wiki, because I am like a beginner here.

Comment: Edit the question and click "CW" checkbox

Comment: click on edit and check box community wiki

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was easy to convert it into a CW.

Comment: If you restrict this only to HTML 4 then people will post things that are already proposed (and implemented in some browsers) in HTML 5. What do you want to get with a list of missing features in HTML 4? If they work in the newer browsers that should be enough.

Comment: I Have corrected. So now users can list missing features HTML 5 also.

Comment: Html5 fixes a huge amount, it's almost an pointless question if you include html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hell, they miss so many features, I wouldn't know where to begin! But here goes:

**(Missing in HTML 4, don't know about 5)**

- Full visual customizability (background colours, borders, and text colours) for *all* elements (including checkboxes, radio buttons, and `select` elements)
- Native input validation (without needing JS) for text inputs: Numeric only, alphabetic characters only, regular expression

Comment: begin with the most important ones.

Answer (score 2):

Date/Time picker controls, rather than always trying to manipulate a textbox, selects, or some other controls to create them.

Comment: The conception of this element presents in HTML5. So hopefully when people finally finish up with HTML5(I think that was for 2012) we can enjoy using Date/Time picker control.

Answer (score 1):

An open enumeration, a "SELECT you can type in" would be handy in some situations.

If pretty much everyone, but not quite, answers the question in one of ten or 15 different ways, you have to either force everyone to type in the answer or have an "other" option with a separate text field.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of intrinsic support for multiple windows (or even just modal dialogs) is **ridiculous**.

Think of the **tens of thousands** of programmer-hours wasted on acrobatic manipulation of `div` elements just to implement a UI that would be trivially easy in a desktop app.

Comment: I would say jQuery is better solution for creating and manipulating multiple windows with their **dialog box**.

Comment: Right... and making sure it stays behind Desktop apps was MicroSoft, who intentionally kept IE   non-standard and lagging behind.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat pointless to list what is missing in HTML 4 since so much has been fixed in HTML 5. And then, most of us can't list what is missing from HTML 5 because we are not familiar enough with it yet.